# Cambridge University paper on Android factory reset still up to date?

Tags: encryption, android, tee

An answer ([Data deleted after encryption - recoverable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/207760/data-deleted-after-encrpytion-recoverable)) came to conclusions, which triggered some questions for me.

Link to the paper: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/Papers/fr_most15.pdf

> Cambridge University researchers tested a range of Android devices
>   running Android and found that in all cases they were able to recover
>   account tokens – which are used to authenticate the 1st time you enter
>   a password (Google, Facebook and WhatsApp). In 80% of cases, they were
>   able to recover the master token, which practically is the main key to
>   the device. Once the master token is recovered, the user’s credential
>   file can be restored and all your data re-synced to the device: that
>   means e-mails, cloud-stored photos, contacts and calendars. So you
>   just offered access to everything!

Is the Master Token the Master Encryption Key used for encrypting the storage when writing data? I don't quite understand this explanation, but I don't think so (?).

> Devices with built-in encryption are not safe from such a problem
>   because they don't provide the required software to fully correctly
>   wipe flash storage.

The paper only discusses Android 2.3 - 4.3 (which are 6 - 9 years old by now).

"Android L (Android 5) is expected to include hardware protection for disk encryption keys, as well as hardware acceleration for encrypted disk access." (https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2014/10/revisiting-android-disk-encryption.html)

The paper doesn't take that into account I suppose?

Isn't the key stored in the TEE by now, which includes a hardware-backed key storage?

> ...after reset, fill the device with useless data to overwrite
>   anything sensitive like the tokens and crypto keys left in flash
>   storage and you should do it without re-registering with Google. You
>   can do this fill by copying something or just by recording a video for
>   as long as you can, at the highest possible resolution, until all your
>   available space is full.

Overwriting doesn't work that way on flash storage, I thought (because of wear leveling)?

Comment: While technically true about the wear leveling, it reduces the chances of recovery massively. Lets say you use 20% of capacity for leveling. That means 1/6 chance the master token is not deleted. If you repeat the process again: delete and rerecord the video  the chances are lowered even more.